# Why am I getting a KeyError when the key clearly exists?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a class `Commit`.

```
class Commit:
    def __init__(self, uid, message):
        self.uid = uid
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.__dict__)
        return textwrap.dedent('''\
        Commit: {uid}

        {message}
        ''').format(self.__dict__)
```

This seems right to me; both keys exists and are non-`None`, as seen from the output of the `print` call:

```
{'message': 'Hello, world!', 'uid': 1}
```

However, the call to `str.format()` on the list line raises a `KeyError`.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "../Pynewood/pnw", line 7, in 
>     cli(sys.argv)
>   File "/Users/daknok/Desktop/Pynewood/pynewood/cli.py", line 11, in cli
>     print(commit)
>   File "/Users/daknok/Desktop/Pynewood/pynewood/commit.py", line 14, in __str__
>     ''').format(self.__dict__)
> KeyError: 'uid'
> ```

Why am I getting this error, while the keys clearly exist in the dictionary?

Comment: You also can use `vars(self)`. I think it looks nicer than `self.__dict__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format) expects kwargs, so you need to expand the dictionary using `**`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return textwrap.dedent('''\
    Commit: {uid}

    {message}
    ''').format(**self.__dict__)
```

Comment: +1.  Example format strings shown [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 3):

*Radek Slupik* is right, `str.format` expects individual keyword arguments, and in the code from the question the `dict` is simply passed as the first positional argument to `format` which would be extended on `{0}` in the format string. So `str.format(**mapping)` should be used.

But since Python 3.2 you can use `str.format_map(mapping)` instead. It works similarly to `str.format(**mapping)`, but it doesn't turn the *mapping* into a `dict`. This allows us to give custom mapping classes to `format`, like in the example from the documentation:

```
>>> class Default(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return key
...
>>> '{name} was born in {country}'.format_map(Default(name='Guido'))
'Guido was born in country'
```

It also looks better and may give a tiny performance boost.